# Sheets: How to prepend with 1 with us phone number

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have a group of multi format phone numbers in a sheets column. I want to remove all non numeric digits and conditionally add a 1 in front (if its not there already). So far I have:

```
=ArrayFormula( (REGEXREPLACE( E1:E , "([^0-9]+)" , "" ) )
```

which removes the non numerics. How do I conditionally prepend with 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(
 IF(E2:E<>"", IF(LEFT(E2:E, 1)<>"1", 
 "1"&E2:E, E2:E))), "([^0-9]+)", ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be this if you wanted to use regexreplace, but @player0 is right, probably easier to use LEFT

```
=regexreplace(A1,"(^[^1])","1$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 TEXTJOIN("♥", 1, QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(E2:E<>"", 
 IF(LEFT(E2:E, 1)<>"1", "1"&E2:E, E2:E), ), "-"), )), , 
 ROWS(E2:E))), "♥", 0))), " ", ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the source data is apparently Plain Text (or easily reformatted as such) a shorter version:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(E4:E="","",regexreplace(1&REGEXREPLACE(E4:E,"\D",""),"^11","1")))
```

(Prepends a `1` in all cases, before stripping one `1` where number would otherwise start `11`.)